# How to query database using react-redux-toolkit in nextjs14

Tags: mongodb, next.js, redux-toolkit

i am trying to use the react-redux-toolkit in my next.js application and im getting the issue and trying to solve it for hours. im seeing similar issues online, most are in nextjs13 below and im using the version 14, but seems not to work in my case, idk if different versions have to do with it but here is the whole error.

```
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/mongocryptd_manager.js:34:24
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/auto_encrypter.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./lib/api/data.ts
./lib/redux/features/filterSlice.ts
./components/products-content/index.tsx
```

Since my app involves databse, i had to do asycn programming. Im referencing my implementation of redux-toolikt from [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk). The documentation is for typescript and not for nextjs specifaclly. And I only know the basic concept of server-side and client-side concept in nextjs since this is my first time using it. I had this same error before but not with redux-toolkit and I just simply solve it by using "use server" or separting codes to other files.

Here's the code of my slice

lib/redux/features/filterSlice.ts

```
export const fetchProductsList = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/fetchProducts",
  async (
    query: any,
    thunkAPI
  ) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetchProducts(query);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e);
    }
  }
);

export interface ProductState {
  products: Product[] | undefined;
}

const initialState: ProductState = {
  products: undefined,
};

export const filterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "filter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchProductsList.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.products = action.payload
    });
  },
});
export const selectFilter = (state: RootState) => state.filter.products;

export default filterSlice.reducer;
```

The error shows when i import and use the *fetchProducts()*

This is the implementation of fetchProducts()

lib/api/data.ts

```
import clientPromise from "../connection";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
import { ProductsCart } from "../definition";

export async function fetchProducts({
  query,
}: {
  query?: string;
}): Promise<any | undefined> {
  try {
    let products;
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("watch-db");
    const regex = new RegExp("\\b" + query + "[a-zA-Z]*\\b", "i");
    products = db.collection("products").find({ name: { $regex: regex } }).toArray();
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Then on a component, im trying to dispatch the *fetchProductsList()*. the error also shows when I import that function into this component

components/products/index.tsx

```
"use client";
import { useAppStore, useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "@/lib/redux/hooks";
import {fetchProductsList} from "@/lib/redux/features/filterSlice";

export default function ProductsContent({ query }: any) {

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProductsList(query));
  }, []);
  const productsList = useAppSelector((state) => state.filter);
  console.log(productsList);
  

  return (
    <>
     ...
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried using the ***getServerSideProps*** on this component but the same error is showing, and another issue using this is i dont know how to pass the *query* to it. As seen, i only passing query thru props from other file to this component.

The other file

app/search/page.tsx

```
import ProductsContent from "@/components/products-content";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { sorting, defaultSort } from "@/lib/constants";
import Sort from "@/components/filter/sort";
import { CardsSkeleton } from "@/components/skeleton";

export default async function SearchPage({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) {
  const {
    query: searchValue,
  } = searchParams as {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
  const query = {
    query: searchValue ? searchValue : "",
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Sort />
      <Suspense key={searchValue} fallback={<CardsSkeleton />}>
        <ProductsContent query={query} />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

the lib, components, and app directories are in same level btw

Comment: Look at the error stacktrace, the code made it through to *at least* your `./lib/api/data.ts` file, then continues into the Mongo code running in the backend. You'll need to investigate your backend code it seems.

Comment: yesss i did that! and what i did then was adding the "use server" directive in that file and all works now!